# Pattern for combining the functions of ?: and ?? operators

Tags: php

I have a function that accepts an array that has loads of data, and one of those pieces of data, for example, is the 'name': `$data = ['name' => 'John'];`

Now, if I want to get the name out of that with a default value, I have two options that I often use.

```
$name = $data['name'] ?? 'Default Name';
$name = $data['name'] ?: 'Default Name';
```

Each one of those applies the default under different circumstances: the first will give me 'Default Name' when the 'name' key isn't defined in the `$data` array, and the second will give me 'Default Name' when the 'name' key IS in the `$data` array, but it's a falsy value. It will ERROR, on the other hand, when the key is not set.

But I want an operator / function that gives me the default under both of those scenarios: when it's falsey, like an empty string or the number 0 or whatever, AND ALSO when the key is not set.

Comment: tbh, I think just using a ternary condition using `empty()` should be ok

Comment: @treyBake what? Can you show me an example?

Comment: `$name = (empty($data['name']) ? 'Default Name' : $data['name']);` - empty checks if key is set as well as false values :)

Comment: was trying to avoid that specifically. That's what I would have done if I didn't mind typing all that stuff

Comment: @TKoL These are same expression.
$name = $data['name'] ?? 'Default Name';
$name = $data['name'] ?: 'Default Name';

Comment: @JuChengJiang are you saying ?? and ?: have the same behavior in general?

Comment: Yes. In both options, it will check the variable with isset() function.

Comment: That's not the case. [see here](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/whats-the-difference-between-null-coalescing-operator-and-ternary-operator-in-php)

Comment: @JuChengJiang that's not true at all

Comment: Just use `empty()` as others have suggested. That's the most "shortcut" way

Comment: @TKoL yeah, is a bit annoying, maybe one day we'll get a operator that compares false values and isset() :)

Comment: `$param ?: 'default'` is equal to `$param ?? 'default';` If you check, that should be same meaning, I think.

Comment: @JuChengJiang don't do that. PHP will throw "Notice: Undefined variable: param" if it's not set. Yes php will still return "default" as the value, but coding in such way is a bad practice.

Comment: @Fahmi Can you explain in detail? Which one of them will get Notice issue?

Comment: If the `['name']` key is unset, then `$data['name'] ?: 'defaultValue';` will error

Comment: This happens in Blade templates specifically for me.

Comment: At least, isset() function is check key and if the ['name'] key is unset, it should be return default value. Do you mean it's value in case? :)

Comment: Note to self, do not name first child: '0'.

Comment: @TKoL sorry. My bad. You were right. Just confused with hard working. lol. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`empty` with the ternary will do the trick:

```
<?php
$data =
[
    ['name'=>'Peter'],
    ['age'=>'23'],
    ['name' => ''],
    ['name' => '0']
];

foreach($data as $entry) {
    echo
        empty($entry['name'])
        ? 'Default'
        : $entry['name']
        , "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Peter
Default
Default
Default
```

Or the less readable:

```
foreach ($data as $entry) {
    $name = $entry['name'] ?? '' ?: 'Default';
    echo $name, "\n";
}
```

Same output as above.

Comment: this is kinda what i was trying to avoid but looks like there's no better option. Wish there was a shorthand operator for this.

Answer (score 0):

So something like this?

```php
isset($x) ? (!$x ? 'default-false' : $x) : 'default-not-set';
```

I'm not sure if you can simplify this with PHP. But you surely can wrap it in a fuction:

```php
function myPickyDefault($value, $defaulNull, $defaultFalse) {
    return isset($value) ? ( !$x ? $defaultFalse : $x) : $defaulNull;
}
```